# How to change my inline styles based on the selected language in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am building a django web application. I wish to change the layout of my website from RTL(right to left) to LTR(left to right). I have implemented the HTML[dir='rtl'] in it. It worked but the main issue is that the layout.

I want the layouts to get switched from LTR to RTL whenever the selected language is arabic.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if not request.session.has_key('currency'):
        request.session['currency'] = settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY

    setting = Setting.objects.get(pk=1)
    # >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> M U L T I   L A N G U G A E >>>>>> START
    defaultlang = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE[0:2]
    currentlang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE[0:2]
    context={'defaultlang': defaultlang}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

page.html

```
<div id="top-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="{% if defaultlang == 'en' %}pull-left {% else %} pull-right{% endif %}">
            <span>{% trans "Welcome to E-shop!" %}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="{% if defaultlang == 'en' %}pull-right {% else %} pull-left{% endif %}">
            <span>GoodBye</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a way to ensure that the classes change when the language is Arabic.

Please kindly help with any suggestions you have.Thanks

Comment: based on your HTML template it seems that, you already tried something, so could you explain why that isn't working? I mean what result do you get when you render that code?

Comment: Only the first class runs. But i want to make one of them render when the English version of the site is active and vice-versa

Comment: then you must pass the `currentlang` variable, not the `defaultlang ` because it's always the same, or you can change the defaultlang value in the database every time the user changes the language